# SpringBoot deployment on Ubuntu with logback configuration fails with FileNotFoundException (Permission Denied)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, ubuntu, spring-logback

I am trying to deploy simple SpringBoot application on `ubuntu` server as an `Upstart` service.
This application has `logback-spring.xml` configuration which points to exact same location where the service log files are created i.e. `/var/log/upstart` directory.

But when I deploy this application it fails with following error indicating some permission issue (**`Permission Denied`**),

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected: 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected: 
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[FILE] - openFile(/var/log/upstart/app.log,true) call failed. java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/log/upstart.app.log (Permission denied)
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[FILE] - openFile(/var/log/upstart/app.log,true) call failed. java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/log/upstart/app.log (Permission denied)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.loadConfiguration(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:153)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.loadConfiguration(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:153) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initializeWithConventions(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:71)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initializeWithConventions(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:71) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initialize(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:49)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initialize(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:49) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.initialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:106)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.initialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:106) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initializeSystem(LoggingApplicationListener.java:262)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initializeSystem(LoggingApplicationListener.java:262) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initialize(LoggingApplicationListener.java:233)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initialize(LoggingApplicationListener.java:233) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:200)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:200) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:176)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:176) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:163)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:163) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:136)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:136) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:119)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:119) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.publishEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:111)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:65)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.publishEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:111) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
```

Logback-spring.xml file,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<!-- Enable jmxConfiguration to allow dynamic level change through spring boot admin -->
<jmxConfigurator/>

<property resource="log.properties" />

<!-- Standard console appender used in all environments. Upstart catches logs and stores in /var/log/upstart-->
<appender name="console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>[%-5level] [%t] %d %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<springProfile name="local">
    <appender name="local" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${log.local.path}/${log.name.async}.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- daily rollover -->
            <fileNamePattern>${log.local.path}/%d{yyyy-MM-dd,aux}/${log.name.async}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <!-- keep 30 days' worth of history -->
            <maxHistory>7</maxHistory>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <!-- or whenever the file size reaches 256MB -->
                <maxFileSize>256MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>%-5level [%t] %d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss.SSS} %logger{35} - %msg%n</Pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
</springProfile>

<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="console"/>
    <appender-ref ref="local"/>
</root>
```

log.properties file,

```
log.local.path=/var/log/upstart
log.name.async=propspace-async
```

Comment: have you tried given read write permission to that location, can you try `chmod 777  /var/log/upstart/`

Comment: /var/log/upstart is a system directory which should not be altered in my opinion. This issue should be common with respect to any such applications using logback or any log framework.@Karim

Comment: This is not a problem with logback, but a problem that Linux doesn't allow your application to write to that directory so if you don't want to change the write permission to that directory choose a different one

Comment: @Karim if I don't give any file appender than deployment works and it creates default logs in same directory. So it is something logback specific.

Comment: you can verfy the permissions by running this command  `ls -l /var/log/upstart` and add the result here

Comment: @Karim I created another directory because the service owner and log directory owner were different. The issue got solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I figured out the issue. Though the error was pretty straight forward, there were some things I need to relook into.

The `service` was `owned` by user `'appuser'` on ubuntu.

The directory (`/var/log/upstart/`) into which the logs were pointed was not permitted to user '`appuser`'. The log directory was owned by user '`root`'. Hence I created another directory (`/var/log/app/`) which is also owned by the same user i.e. 'appuser' and started the application.

It solved the issue.